# Adding more than one item into composite table with laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, forms

I currently have a database for Recipe Management with 3 tables: Recipe table holding everything but ingredients, ingredients table with the ingredients name and category and then a composite table joining the two to avoid the many to many relationship the composite table has quantity and measurement aswell as the two primary keys.

I have a form which the users can fill out which adds to the database, however i cant workout how to allow the users to add more than one ingredient at a time and have it submit at once, for example the user fills out recipe name / desc etc, and then I want to allow them to add all of their ingredients in the form along with measurements.

I would like the form to be something like

```
Recipe Name: Cupcake

Recipe Desc: Its a cupcake

Ingredient  Quantity Measurement

Large Egg....2............Null

Butter...........150........grams

Milk...............3........... tbsp

[+] Add Ingredient

[Submit]
```

And then the Recipe_Ingredients table would be something like

```
RecipeID: 1 Ingredient ID: 1 Quantity:2 Measurement:Null

RecipeID: 1 Ingredient ID: 2 Quantity:150 Measurement:Grams

RecipeID: 1 Ingredient ID: 3 Quantity:3 Measurement:Tbsp
```

Requested saving code:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $id = Auth::id(); 
    
    $recipe = new Recipe();
    $recipe->name = $request->name;
    $recipe->description = $request->description;
    $recipe->instructions = $request->instructions;
    $recipe->cooktime = $request->cooktime;
    $recipe->preptime = $request->preptime;
    $recipe->serves = $request->serves;
    $recipe->cuisine = $request->cuisine;
    $recipe->diet = $request->diet;
    $recipe->userid = $id;
    if ($image = $request->file('image')){
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        if($image->move('images',$name)){
            $recipe->image = $name;
            $recipe->save();
        };
    }
    return redirect()->back();
    
    
    $recipe->save();

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? How's this different from any other multi-cell form?

Comment: Sorry im very new to this, im not familiar with multi-cell form, my problem is that i dont know how to allow the user to enter as many ingredients as they want, and then send all of the ingredient/quantity/measurements to the database, i think its the composite table thats confusing it for me. I want to store them almost like an array although i know its not good to use an array in mysql.

Comment: Well do you know how to send *one* ingredient/quantity/measurement to the database?

Comment: Please add in your question the code part where you are saving recipe to the database

Comment: Code added @Psycho.

Comment: Trying that now @Strawberry.

Comment: do you know oneToMany relation in laravel?

Comment: Not specifcally in laravel no @Psycho but the recipe table would be a many to many with the ingredients table hence the composite table.

Comment: are you familiar with vue.js or jquery?

Comment: @Psycho Not particuarly this is my first big project as im still studying at Uni.

Comment: then, it is better for you to follow some tutorials and when you face problems or specific errors may occur then find question+solutions in SO

Comment: Yea i have been doing that this is the first one i havent been able to solve on my own.